# ¿Cómo inventariar un conjunto de Base de Datos y todos sus objetos?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Quisiera saber si hay forma de sacar información (número de tablas, tamaño correspondiente, cuántos registros, etc.) pero por cada base de datos dentro de una instancia. Sé que la consulta para determinar las bases de datos dentro de un servidor es:

```
USE master  
GO  
SELECT name, database_id, create_date FROM sys.databases  
GO
```

... y que la consulta para determinar los detalles de una tabla dentro de una base de datos es:

```
use database
go
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
go
```

Pero no sé cómo hacerlo ambos en una una sola consulta y que me de como resultado algo como lo que muestro en la tabla de abajo. Y si fuera posible también los stores y JOBS, me piden hacer un inventario, el problema es que tienen más de 450 bases de datos repartidos en 20 servidores. No lo terminaría nunca haciendo las consultas de arriba base por base. Me imagino que se puede implementar un SP, pero no lo he logrado aún.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier idea o sugerencia sería de mucha ayuda, o tal vez ya exista algún procedimiento almacenado etc.

Comment: ¿Con qué motor de base de datos deseas recolectar esta información? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL...

Comment: Estoy trabajando con SQL SERVER 2008, la recopilación se me hace complicada por la cantidad de base de datos, como lo menciono arriba en el mensaje. Con este motor hay implementado 12 servidores (instancias) entre físicos y virtuales, y necesito la relación de tablas pero "amarradas" por base de datos. Ya sería ideal si hay un procedimiento para sacar de hachazo en las 12 instancias, de lo contrario tendré que trabajar de servidor en servidor, 12 es una cantidad manejable, pero si trabajo a nivel de base de datos no podré, son demasiados.

Comment: Ah muy bien. De hecho, Weimar ha respondido a tu pregunta, me parece acertada la respuesta dado lo que preguntas. Yo probé su script en un manejador de base de datos de SQL Server 2012 y me funcionó muy bien, ahí tengo como 18 bases de datos y si llegará a existir alguna duda le puedes escribir algún comentario.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta utilizando la utilidad `sp_msforeachdb` de la siguiente manera. Lo que se hace acá es crear una tabla temporal donde se almacenará la información recopilada, primero se obtiene la información de las tablas y luego la de los procedimientos, al final se le hace un `SELECT` a la tabla temporal:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Inventory') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #Inventory 

CREATE TABLE #Inventory
(
    DatabaseName nvarchar(1024)
    ,ObjectType nvarchar(1024)
    ,ObjectName nvarchar(1024)
    ,SchemaName nvarchar(1024)  
    ,RowCounts int
    ,TotalSpaceKB int
    ,UsedSpaceKB int
    ,UnusedSpaceKB int
)
INSERT INTO #Inventory
EXEC sp_msforeachdb 
'
SELECT  
    ''?'' AS DatabaseName,
    ''Table'' AS ObjectType,
    t.NAME AS ObjectName,
    s.Name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM 
    [?].sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    [?].sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    [?].sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    [?].sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE ''dt%'' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    t.Name
'

INSERT INTO #Inventory
EXEC sp_msforeachdb 
'SELECT 
    ''?'' AS DatabaseName
    ,''Procedure'' As ObjectType
    , SPECIFIC_NAME As ObjectName
    , SPECIFIC_SCHEMA AS SchemaName
    , 0 As RowCounts
    , 0 As TotalSpaceKB
    , 0 As UsedSpaceKB
    , 0 As UnusedSpaceKB
FROM information_schema.routines 
WHERE routine_type = ''PROCEDURE'''

SET NOCOUNT OFF
SELECT * FROM #Inventory ORDER BY DatabaseName, ObjectType DESC, ObjectName
```

Comment: gracias por la información, con respecto al resultado de la consulta, me salen dos tablas temporales, la primera, que es la tabla creada #Inventory y la segunda #qtemp, esta última no recuerdo haberla visto.
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4c1i.png
¿Se generó con la ejecución del script (#qtemp)? ¿La tendría que descartar también? Aunque lo cierto es que cuando hago consultas posteriores sobre el tempdb solo figura el #inventory.

saludos.

Comment: Esa tabla a la que haces referencia no pertenece a este script. De pronto la puede crear el procedimiento almacenado sp_msforeachdb, pero no tengo la certeza de eso.

Comment: También es importante que marques la repuesta como correcta, en el caso que te haya servido para resolver tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Claro que sí, el script de arriba lo ejecuté en un servidor local de prueba, y obviamente listó las bases de datos dentro de ella, incluyendo las BD del sistema (master, tempdb, model, etc..)Dentro de tempdb figura la tabla temporal #inventory creada para el fin de la consulta y otra adicional (#qtemp) que no sé por que lo hace. Aunque como te repito esta última no figura cuando la trato de ubicar en tempdb, solo aparece en el resultado del script, pero creo que no es relevante, ya los quité con un WHERE.

Comment: Weimar, encontré un inconveniente en la lista de los procedimientos almacenados, se repite en todas las bases de datos. ¿Podrías verificarlos? Lo que hice fue comentar parte del script referente a la inserción de tablas, y me dí cuenta que los stores que se listan por cada base de datos se repiten.

Answer (score 0):

una forma clásica de inventario de objetos en base de datos es un listado de los objetos mas usuado y comunes, aqui te dejo un script para que obtengas el listado de objetos, si deseas puedes filtrar mas objetos en la vista '**SYS.OBJECTS**' para completar tu inventario.

```
SELECT     
T.TYPE_DESC,
S.NAME AS ESQUEMA,
T.NAME AS NOMBRE
FROM SYS.TABLES T
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
SYS.SCHEMAS S ON T.SCHEMA_ID = S.SCHEMA_ID
UNION
SELECT     
V.TYPE_DESC,
S.NAME AS ESQUEMA,
V.NAME AS NOMBRE
FROM SYS.VIEWS V
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
SYS.SCHEMAS S ON V.SCHEMA_ID = S.SCHEMA_ID
UNION
SELECT     
P.TYPE_DESC,
S.NAME AS ESQUEMA,
P.NAME AS NOMBRE
FROM SYS.PROCEDURES P
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
SYS.SCHEMAS S ON P.SCHEMA_ID = S.SCHEMA_ID
UNION
SELECT     
TR.TYPE_DESC,
'' AS ESQUEMA,
TR.NAME AS NOMBRE
FROM SYS.TRIGGERS TR
UNION
SELECT 
O.TYPE_DESC,
S.NAME AS ESQUEMA,
O.NAME AS NOMBRE
FROM SYS.OBJECTS O 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
SYS.SCHEMAS S ON O.SCHEMA_ID = S.SCHEMA_ID
WHERE O.TYPE_DESC = 'SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION'
ORDER BY 2,1
```